(S)ARIMAX Differencing and Exogenous Features
I am trying to work on a model to predict website visitors for the next 28 days using historical daily traffic data from the past 3 years.
As it is a time series problem, often ETS & ARIMA-family models are suggested to start with to capture the temporal nature of the data. In my case as I have some exogenous variables I thought to start with (S)ARIMAX model(s) as ETS-family not supporting the exogenous variables.
My timeseries has annual seasonality, trend, as well as shocks (due promotional activities) which looks like below:

I understand that the ARIMA family models are not good capturing sudden shocks (orange promotion days) as the model tries to generalise coefficients for both AR & MA terms across the whole training data, and the promotion shocks would be impacting highly on the coefficient for the base days and vice versa.
Therefore, I though to focus only forecasting the base days (blue) first. I replaced all the orange data points with null values and then interpolated the days connecting last same weekday with the next same weekday in linear manner. After that the data looks as below:

As we can see from the pattern the current timeseries doesn't meet the stationary requirement of the ARIMA model. Meaning, I can enter parameters D=364 (remove/reduce annual seasonality) and d=1 (remove the trend). With these settings, when running cross validation for SARIMA model (without exogenous variables) for horizon 28 days for 4 different windows I get MAPE ~ 7% for the original scale of the data, which is relatively good starting point.
At this point, I was excited and thought if it does so good job already without the exogenous regressors, how the results will look like once I add them in...
First looking at the relationship of traffic and marketing spend and it is somewhat linear. Data was rescaled only using the non-promotional days (so scale changed from the last figure).

After feeding in the exogenous variable, and again using d=1 and D=364 and running the SARIMAX model I get MAPE ~12%, so it got much worse by adding marketing spend which seemed to be highly related. I thought this must be due to the differencing, and in fact this seems to be the case:
When I do seasonal differencing to both visitors and marketing spending the correlation coefficient decreases significantly:

Finally when I remove the trend with d=1 the last drop of the relationship is gone:

How would I overcome the problem to make the time series stationary but not to lose the valuable insights given the marketing spend?
Some could argue that "but 7% forecast is already relatively good, so just use the model without the marketing spend"... However, I need to capture the change in case the marketing spend changes significantly for the upcoming days/weeks.
Any support and suggestions are much appreciated and welcome! :)
[Edit1]: clarified that MAPE results were from cross validation
